# How to format unrecognized USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, boot, partitioning, unetbootin

I have used Unetbootin on one of my USB drive, and it seems to have partitioned it some way that it's no longer recognized by any OS. It's not even listed when I turn on my computer and press F12 to list the boot options.

I have tried to use GParted and even OpenSuse Partioner but none of them were able to recognize the drive. However I'm still able to hear that sound when I plug it in, meaning that a USB device has been connected. On Windows, I can see it listed in the device manager but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it helps to clear the first sector of that device. So on Linux, try this as non-root:

- insert the usb drive, check `dmesg` to see what device it gets asigned (assuming /dev/sdc here)
- dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1
- fdisk /dev/sdc (add a partition in here)
- mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1 (or any other filesystem you want)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working though, but I think we're getting closer : the last line of dmesg is "[  126.489702] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk" and /dev/sdc is created when I insert the drive. But then when I run the second command, I get this error message : "dd: opening ‘/dev/sdc’: No medium found"

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue after using Clonezilla where the USB drive was smaller than the source hard drive (expert mode) and USB would not mount on XP, Linux 17 or Linux 18 computers, or Clonezilla live again.  USB drive was did not mount on Macbook but 'disk utility' first aid option fixed the drive.